# How to use babel loader on node_modules in webpack for ES6+?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have a react project and all the extensions of everything is .js, none of them use .jsx. I downloaded a new library react-pdf-js-infinite and it uses .jsx. In my webpack the loader as exceptions running on all of node_modules. How do i set it up so that it will run on the .jsx file in my node_module. I constantly get an error when i am trying to run my production build with webpack for it. Saying this file might need a loader and it is when the build is encounter the ecma standard of static propTypes within the class of the component. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class PDF extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    x: propType.String
  }
}
```